# Python- Retrieve information from a File- a matter of structures

Tags: python, file, multidimensional-array

I have a question: is there any way that python retrieved a python structure from a file instead of retrieved everything as String?.

Let me explain in detail:

I have three functions/Methods inside my class. I ´ve just copied and pasted the piece of code that I want to analyze.

One method is for deletion, one for open a file and one for writing a file as follow:

```
def download_data(self,lista_contactos):
    with open(global_properties.file_contact, 'a', newline='') as fw:
        writter = csv.writer(fw,delimiter=',')
        writter.writerow([lista_contactos])

def Open_File(self):
    with open(global_properties.file_contact) as fr:
        read = csv.reader(fr)
        lista_contacto = []
        for each_row in read:
            lista_contacto += each_row
        print("El archivo es {}".format(lista_contacto))
        return lista_contacto

def delete_file(self):
    a_borrar = []
    a_borrar = self.Open_File()
    print("SELECT THE NAME TO BE DELETED")
    a_modif = str(input(''))
    value = ''
    new_value = ''
    for i in a_borrar:
        print(type(a_borrar))
        print(type(i))
        print(i)
```

When the file is written it is saved as a dictionary inside a list which make sense because I want to save my contacts in a file to retrieved their information then. Maybe I want to retrieve just names or surnames or emails from the whole list, so for that reason I save my data as a dictionary.

"[{'nombre': 'Emiliano', 'apellido': 'Gramajo', 'telefono': '00000000', 'email': 'emilramajo@il.com', 'tipo de contacto': 'P'}]"
"[{'nombre': 'Elizabeth', 'apellido': 'Istillarrrte', 'telefono': '0000000', 'email': 'elizabeth.arte@gl.com', 'tipo de contacto': 'Personal'}]"
"[{'nombre': 'Karen', 'apellido': 'Noguera', 'telefono': '11111111', 'email': 'kals@gl.com', 'tipo de contacto': 'P'}]"

But when I retrieved the information, all information is retrieved as str ( I know because I print their types). So which would be my approach? to save all information as a list without keys or is there any way to say Python that I am trying to retrieved a dictionary from a file to handle this dictionary inside the list as it should be?.

Note: if you ask me, I ´d prefer the second one, because , either I will have to handle everything as an string and starting to split each key-value, save them into a list and get the information, or save them as plain test without keys which will make more difficult to understand or find which data I will need to print or retrieve then.

none of my approaches helped me to retrieve the information to be deleted or modified

Comment: Don't try to save information to a file by converting it to a str like this. Use a format that's designed for easy round-trip saving and loading—JSON, JSONLines, pickle, etc. They all have different strengths and weaknesses, but they're all better than just writing out `str(mylistofdicts)` and then trying to figure out what to do with it when you read it back in. (If the thing you're trying to save is just a list of list of dicts of strings, JSON is perfect for that.)

Comment: You' re right . I didn't think in Json file.